# How can I rotate an image easily on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, images, rotate

How can I rotate an image on a Mac easily?

In Windows, it's very easy with the default Windows Photo Viewer; as seen in this screenshot, there are 2 icons to rotate the image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Preview to rotate the image. That is the defualt program for images in Mac so you should be able to just double-click the image and follow the instructions below.

Via Preview Help:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Preview.app can do that. In the menu select Tools `->` Rotate left, Rotate right